# Placing circles in Sunburst arcs

Tags: d3.js, svg, trigonometry

I need to place circles in the sunburst arcs, close to the outer radius either in the middle or in the sides as in the mock-up in the **B Unit** slice.

Please use this sunburst example to play around: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonuz/4jmaytf5/)

```
    var circles = g.append("circle")
    .attr("cx",
        function(d) {
            return arc.centroid(d)[0];
        })
    .attr("cy",
        function(d) {
            return arc.centroid(d)[1];
        })
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "blue");
```

[image]

Comment: I have same issue.
If you solved this, can you tell me how to place circle at the outer radius?